# Serialize and Deserialize domain events to persist and retrieve from Event Store in generic implementation

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, domain-events, eventstoredb

I am using DDD with CQRS and Event Sourcing.
I need to use an Event Store (specifically [this event store](https://eventstore.org/)) within my custom implementation of `IEventStore` to persist and retrieve domain events but I am having difficulties with the approach to take that deals with serialization/deserialization.

This is the interface I am implementing:

```
public interface IEventStore
{
    Task<IEnumerable<IDomainEvent>> GetEventsAsync(Identity aggregateIdentity, Type aggregateType);

    Task PersistAsync(IAggregateRoot aggregateRoot, IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> domainEvents);
}
```

Outside my implementation of `IEventStore` I can have mappers from every `IDomainEvent` into some serializable/deserializable EventDto or json string. That's not a problem.
But these are my restrictions:

- my domain events are **immutable objects** that implement `IDomainEvent` (i.e: no setters)
- my domain events are not always easily serializable/deserializable in a generic way. **Often they have abstract or interface properties**, so the concrete mappers between my domain events and some serializable object such as string json or event DTO are decided outside my `IEventStore` implementation.
- My `IEventStore` implementation needs to be generic in a way that **if I add new domain event types, I should not need to touch anything** within the `IEventStore` implementation
- My `IEventStore` implementation can receive injected some specific implementations of `IMapper<TSource, TDestination>`, so that I could use a them to serialize/deserialize between specific types (not interfaces).

  ```
  public interface IMapper<in TSource, out TDestination>
  {
      TDestination Map(TSource source); // I have implementations of this if needed
  }
  ```

This below is my attempt:

```
public class MyEventStore
    : IEventStore
{
    private readonly IStreamNameFactory _streamNameFactory;
    private readonly IEventStoreConnection _eventStoreConnection; //this is the Greg Young's EventStore product that I want to use as database
    private readonly IDomainEventFactory _domainEventFactory;
    private readonly IEventDataFactory _eventDataFactory;

    public EventStore(
        IStreamNameFactory streamNameFactory, 
        IEventStoreConnection eventStoreConnection, 
        IDomainEventFactory domainEventFactory, 
        IEventDataFactory eventDataFactory)
    {
        _streamNameFactory = streamNameFactory;
        _eventStoreConnection = eventStoreConnection;
        _domainEventFactory = domainEventFactory;
        _eventDataFactory = eventDataFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<IDomainEvent>> GetEventsAsync(
        Identity aggregateIdentity, 
        Type aggregateType)
    {
        var aggregateIdentityValue = aggregateIdentity.Value;
        var streamName = _streamNameFactory.Create(aggregateIdentityValue, aggregateType);

        var streamEventSlice =
            await _eventStoreConnection.ReadStreamEventsForwardAsync(streamName, 0, Int32.MaxValue, false);

        var domainEvents = streamEventSlice
            .Events
            .Select(x => _domainEventFactory.Create(x));

        return domainEvents;
    }

    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "PossibleMultipleEnumeration")]
    public async Task PersistAsync(
        IAggregateRoot aggregateRoot, 
        IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> domainEvents)
    {
        var numberOfEvents = domainEvents.Count();
        var aggregateRootVersion = aggregateRoot.Version;
        var originalVersion = aggregateRootVersion - numberOfEvents;
        var expectedVersion = originalVersion - 1;

        var aggregateIdentityValue = aggregateRoot.AggregateIdentity.Value;
        var aggregateRootType = aggregateRoot.GetType();
        var streamName = _streamNameFactory.Create(aggregateIdentityValue, aggregateRootType);
        var assemblyQualifiedName = aggregateRootType.AssemblyQualifiedName;

        var eventsToStore = domainEvents.Select(x => _eventDataFactory.Create(x, assemblyQualifiedName));

        await _eventStoreConnection.AppendToStreamAsync(streamName, expectedVersion, eventsToStore);
    }
}
```

The problems is mainly, as you can imagine, in the `IDomainEventFactory` implementation. I need a class that implements the following interface:

```
public interface IDomainEventFactory
{
    IDomainEvent Create(ResolvedEvent resolvedEvent);
}
```

This class needs to **know which specific `IDomainEvent` does it need to deserialize the resolvedEvent to at runtime**. In other words, if the event being retrieved is a json representation of `MyThingCreatedEvent` maybe I can use a service such as `IMapper<ResolvedEvent, MyThingCreatedEvent>`. But if the event being retrieved is a json representation of `MyThingUpdatedEvent` then I would need a service such as `IMapper<ResolvedEvent, MyThingUpdatedEvent>`.

Some approaches came to my mind.

**OPTION 1:**
I thought I could have the `IDomainEventFactory` implementation use the autofac `IComponentContext` so that at runtime I could somehow manage to do some `_componentContext.Resolve(theNeededType)`. But I don't know how to retrieve the IMapper that I need. Maybe this is something possible but I doubt it.

**OPTION 2:**
Maybe I could have some mapping service such as IBetterMapper such as

```
public interface IBetterMapping
{
    TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source) where TDestination : class;
}
```

so that my factory can delegate the concern of knowing how to deserialize anything into `TDestination`. But I would have the same problem: I don't know how to create a type at runtime from a string, for example, to do something like `_myBetterMapper.Map<WhichTypeHere>` and there is the additional problem of implementing that Map method, which I guess would require some registration table and based on the type choose one or another specific mapper.

I am really stuck with this. Hopefully I get some help from you guys! :)

**UPDATE**: I have implemented my own solution and uploaded the project here in my personal repo: https://gitlab.com/iberodev/DiDrDe.EventStore.Infra.EventStore
The solution I went with is to keep the event store wrapper agnostic but to provide custom serializer/deserializer at DI registration for those events that are a bit "special". EventStore allows adding custom metadata headers, so I am using some custom headers to specify concrete implementation types on each data stream so that I know where to deserialize when retrieving the persisted events.

Comment: I am thinking of another idea as OPTION 3: Would the decorator or similar pattern be an option? Could I keep the same `IDomainEvent` and `IEventStore` interfaces but "wrap" my domain events with some serializer-deserializer capabilities. I have only seen the decorator pattern used to "chain" calculations but never to add methods that don't exist in the abstract class or interface, so maybe this is a silly comment.

Comment: you're making this way too hard by trying to encapsulate abstract and framework things. First get something sensible working using the standard examples. forget the IDomainEvent marker interface stuff and just use plain classes that json.net can just roundtrip before getting mappers involved. And Resharper is correct about the double iteration - use arrays

Comment: how would you go making DTO immutable and able to be serialized and deserialized into without public setters and without Newtonsoft attributes polluting the DTO? It's an option to explore, but I think my question and the goal is valid unless there's a better way

Comment: I'm saying for your events... just `{get;set;}` properties, just keep the types simple with no transformations, marker interfaces of any kind. the folded aggregate state is a completely different matter

Comment: JSON can be deserialized against private setters if you use a contract resolver that uses reflection.

Comment: there is no good reason to make events not just have read-writable properties - we're not trying to secure against hackers - we're trying to write simple easy to read code. No matter what any book anywhere says about encapsulation or abstraction, you still get to think for yourself.

Comment: Kit, yes, I could use reflection to "hack" the deserialization but I would try to avoid it. However I was thinking of decorating my `IDomainEvent` with serialize and deserialize capability so that each event knows how to print itself into Json for example?

Comment: At the end the main issue remains: how to know which specific mapper to use given a list of `IDomainEvent`. It does not matter whether I map/unmap before using EventStore (in its client) or delay this until EventStore's execution. At the end in my domain I expect concrete types of `IDomainEvent` and at some point I must convert them to serializable objects (let's say EventDto) and deserialize back into the proper EventDto.
There must be a way, maybe using reflection? I'd like something like looping on `IDomainEvent` collection, grab its type and instantiate a specific mapper from DI container

Comment: if you use json.net, you can attach converters via attributes without any explicit mappers involved. I do agree you should do this in a controlled fashion between app layer and ES, but a) you don't need IDomainEvent for anything b) you're overthinking it. I have thought and fought a lot about this but dont have code to show right now newer than https://github.com/bartelink/FunDomain (that's in a pipeline to opensourcing atm), but I've tried it many different ways and keeping the events as simple types (in discriminated unions if you have lang support) is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

I have come to realize with time that the whole approach was a bad practice. I think a domain event should never have abstract (polymorphic) properties that could take different shape and therefore have issues when deserializing to know exactly what shape had the event been serialized into.

The problem is not technical (although for that, my answer below is still valid) but rather philosophical.

I strongly believe that domain events should only use basic types. Things that don't change (string, int, maybe some "safe" custom types such as money, etc.). It does no make much sense to have polymorphic domain events. **If an event can take different shapes probably we are talking about different events**.

It's important to take into consideration that a very old event (e.g: an event that was raised a year ago) also has to be deserialized when creating a projection (e.g: during a replay, or simply during the instantiation of an aggregate with event sourcing) and therefore this event should be deserialized properly without failing. Imagine the mess if for whatever reason somebody modified one of the classes that event was using and now the old info is not deserializable into the new class. We would be violating the most fundamental thing in event sourcing.

That's why I think we shouldn't use domain events with complex objects unless we are 100% sure these classes won't change, and we shouldn't use polymorphic domain events at all.

---

I have implemented a wrapper over EventStore .NET Client that implements my `IEventStore` interface and abstracts my client application from anything behind the scenes.

```
public interface IEventStore
{
    Task<IEnumerable<IDomainEvent>> GetEventsAsync(Guid aggregateId, Type aggregateType);
    Task PersistAsync(IAggregateRoot aggregateRoot, IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> domainEvents);
}
```

The way I solved the main problem with serialization/deserialization is by providing custom serializer/deserializer for the domain events that are "special" (because they have abstract or interface properties that couldn't be deserialized unless knowing its specific concrete type). Also for each domain event persisted I save metadata headers stating which specific domain event type it is and which specific serializable event type it is.

In other words, the flow goes like this when persisting:
`IDomainEvent -> convert to a serializable type (if needed) -> transform in bytes -> save stream data`

and when retrieving
`Stream Data -> transform to serializable type -> transform to IDomainEvent`

**I have uploaded the whole project in my personal repository in GitLab** here:
https://gitlab.com/iberodev/DiDrDe.EventStore.Infra.EventStore
, feel free to have a look and run all the integration and unit tests with xUnit to understand it. And of course feel free to provide any feedback!

The heavy lifting on my solution is in the part of the client that needs to use an event store. It's the responsibility of its infrastructure layer (Autofac registration in its host application) to register EventStore using an Autofac extension and to provide the required custom serializers/deserializers if needed.

That way I can keep the implementation of the EventStore wrapper completely agnostic to specific settings and to specific domain events. It's a generic solution.

The [README](https://gitlab.com/iberodev/DiDrDe.EventStore.Infra.EventStore/blob/master/README.md) of the project clarifies this, but basically event store can be registered like this if the domain events are serializable (no abstract properties):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); // Autofac container
builder
    .RegisterEventStore(
        ctx =>
        {
            var eventStoreOptions =
                new EventStoreOptions
                {
                    ConnectionString = "ConnectTo=tcp://admin:changeit@127.0.0.1:1113; HeartBeatTimeout=500";
                };
            return eventStoreOptions;
        });
var container = builder.Build();
```

and like this if there are domain events that are special because they have abstract properties:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .RegisterEventStore(
        ctx =>
        {
            var eventStoreOptions =
                new EventStoreOptions
                {
                    ConnectionString = "ConnectTo=tcp://admin:changeit@127.0.0.1:1113; HeartBeatTimeout=500";
                };
            return eventStoreOptions;
        },
        ctx =>
        {
            var customDomainEventMappersOptions =
                new CustomDomainEventMappersOptions()
                    .UsesCustomMappers<FakeDomainEventNotSerializable, FakeSerializableEvent>(
                        domainEvent =>
                        {
                            var mapper =
                                new FakeDomainEventNotSerializableToFakeSerializableEventMapper();
                            var result = mapper.Map(domainEvent);
                            return result;
                        },
                        serializableEvent =>
                        {
                            var mapper =
                                new FakeSerializableEventToFakeDomainEventNotSerializableMapper();
                            var result = mapper.Map(serializableEvent);
                            return result;
                        });
            return customDomainEventMappersOptions;
        });

var container = builder.Build();
```

Comment: I must say, with time I decided having domain events that are not "easily" serializable or deserializable is a bad practice. See my update